# Can AWS MFA work as follows?

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services

In order to log into AWS MFA is required. But if I had a program running on an EC2 instance that invoked AWS services via API calls, would such a program also need to authenticate using MFA or would this not be required because we are already "in?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFA is only required when logging into the AWS web console with a username/password. When you make API calls you would use an IAM access key, or even better (since your program is running on EC2) an IAM instance profile, which doesn't require MFA.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

API calls can be *made* to require MFA as well using an IAM policy. However, if you were to deploy such policy, you could also exclude VPC-internal subnets from the MFA requirement so that MFA would only be required when accessing the AWS API endpoints from the outside.

Here's a link to my repository which contains an example enforcement policy (see `example-mfa-policies/EnforceMFA.txt`): https://github.com/vwal/awscli-mfa